# Lua, table imprime solo nils

Tags: lua

En una tabla guardo todos los valores que me indica el usuario con un ciclo for pero al momento de imprimirlos solo me devuelve nils

```
for i=1,n do
    io.write("Por favor deme el valor de a" .. i .. ": ")
    a = io.stdin:read("*n")
    tablaA[i] = a
end
```

Comment: Hola @Giovanni. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías mostrar el código completo? Es decir, si el problema es al momento de imprimir la tabla, estaría bueno ver cómo intentás imprimirla. Además, ¿estás inicializando la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

Hola Giovanni a lo mejor tu problema era la forma en que imprimias los valores, no se exactamente como lo hiciste pero aqui dejo una implementacion.

```
io.write("Ingrese la cantidad de valores a ingresar ")
local n=io.stdin:read("*n")

local tablaA={}
for i=1,n do
   io.write("Por favor deme el valor de a" .. i .. ": ")
   tablaA[i] = io.stdin:read("*n")
end

for i,number in ipairs(tablaA) do io.write(number.." ") end
```

Answer (score 0):

Es preferible que añadas los datos con table.insert para añadirlos por rango, primero te dejo el código más claro y más corto:

```
io.read() -- lee valores

table.insert(tabla, elemento) -- inserta elementos por indice

tonumber(valor) -- podemos validar si es númerico y evitarnos errores.

tabla = {} -- estamos declarando una tabla
```

El código podría ser de esta forma:

```
elementos = {} -- declaramos una tabla como lista
num = nil -- declaramos num como nulo
while(not tonumber(num)) do -- hacemos un bucle mientras no sea númerico, recuerda la función "tonumber()"
    if (not num) then -- si es nulo imprimimos un mensaje
        print("Ingresa un NUMERO:")
    else -- y si no, el siguiente, y salir del bucle hasta que obligatoriamente sea un número
        print("No ingresaste un número:")
    end
    num = io.read() -- leemos el dato durante el bucle hasta obtener el númerico
end

for i=1, tonumber(num) do -- recuerda que las listas en Lua inician desde 1, ponemos que lea desde uno siempre y cuando no alcanze el tamaño del número, io.read() retorna una cadena(string) así que lo convertimos a númerico
    print("Ingresa el elemento "..i.." para añadir:") -- leemos los datos
    table.insert(elementos, io.read()) -- insertamos los datos que se lean en la tabla 'elementos'
end

lista = '{' -- una simple vista para que el usuario vea que elementos insertó
for i,v in pairs(elementos) do
    lista = lista..'"'..v..'"'
    if not (i == #elementos) then
        lista = lista..', ' -- si no es el limite, inserta una coma y espacio separandolos
    end
end
lista = lista..'}' -- seramos nuestra "lista" creada que en realidad es una cadena
print("Los elementos en la tabla son los siguientes:\n"..lista) -- le damos al usuario los datos que insertó
```